# How to know who made a negative entry on my Schufa?

Tags: germany

Currently I am looking for a new flat and I need to have a Schufa to do that. To my surprise, I have a negative entry here. This:

[image]

<sup>(The pink things are identification data removed by me)</sup>

With text:

> Keine Abgabe der Vermögensauskunft
>
> Aus öffentlichen Verzeichnissen stammt die Information, dass der genannte Verbraucher seine Vermögensverhältnisse nicht offengelegt hat. Weitere Informationen können Sie online nachlesen unter meineSCHUFA.de > Service > Privatinsolvenz, Schuldnerverzeichnisdaten.

I would happily give an English translation, but I cannot. It is in hardcore bookkeeping/legal jargon, for which my German is not enough. Not even Google translate can give adequate translations.

My current best estimate as to what could it mean is roughly:

> No credit data
>
> From public sources came the information, that you did not pay something what you should have. You can check further informations here (link to crap doc, in the same legal jargon)

It seems I was not very pedant some years ago. As best as I can remember, it was likely a ticket control "problem" in the public transit of a nearby big city. But my memories are cloudy. It can be a totally different thing as well.

How could I know what is going on? I want to pay it if there is really something outstanding. *But first I would need to find this entity, then ask them if I still owe them. Then pay if yes, or ask them to remove the entry if I not.*

What does it mean? How can I find the originator of this entry?

Comment: A better translation: *No submission of asset information:* **The information comes from public registers that the named consumer has not disclosed his financial situation.** Not **disclosing** and not **paying** are 2 different things. The event is from 2018-08-09. So try to find out what happened on that date. Is this the result of a **Datenkopie** which can be applied for here: [meineSchufa.de > Produkte > Datenkopie (nach Art. 15 DS-GVO)](https://www.meineschufa.de/index.php?site=11_3)?

Comment: @MarkJohnson I applied for one just yesterday (finding this link by googling for "schufa site:stackexchange.com" :-) ), but I am nearly sure: it will miss exactly this information piece.

Comment: @MarkJohnson No. It was a quick schufa query by the immobilienscout24. Also meineschufa.de has some web access from the dinosaur-era (like blocked accunts on unknown reason, requiring phone calls to reactivate), I do not use it now. As I used it, it was always crap.

Comment: A debt enforcement agent or bailiff requested that you provide a statement pf assets to enforce a debt but you did not do so. Have you checked Vollstreckungsportal?

Comment: @xngtng No, but thanks the tip! It is about https://www.vollstreckungsportal.de ? Registration needs there a new German Personalausweiss, but I have no German Personalausweis et al, because I am not a German citizen. I am looking for other ways to register (possibly needing a lot of phone calls, of course in worktime, and this all to discover, who I need to pay).

Comment: @GraySheep I think it also works with the biometric residence permit if you have one.

Comment: @GraySheep, xngtng For this you must use the application: [AusweisApp2 - Startseite](https://www.ausweisapp.bund.de/ausweisapp2/) and may be used with a present day ID or a electronic residence permit, assuming you chose to activate the online function when recieving the card.

Comment: Don't use Google Translate for German.  Use Deepl for German, or for any other language that Deepl covers.  Deepl says this: "No submission of the statement of assets
The information that the named consumer has not disclosed his financial circumstances comes from public directories. You can find more information online at meineSCHUFA.de > Service > Privatinsolvenz, Schuldnerverzeichnisdaten."

Comment: @Kyralessa This is not strickly true. The result is often dependent on the source (writer). *Google Translate* is good for federal laws, but often brings bad results for state laws. In this case, the result that can be seen in my first comment, is from *GT* and returns for **öffentlichen Verzeichnissen** a meaningful result (public *registers*), whereas *Deepl* result is out of context (public *directories*), since the word **Verzeichnissen** can have different meanings based on the context. This is a major problem for all translater programs, which is why the results must always be checked.